# Does God help only if Punya deposit is available?

Tags: scripture, gods, karma, prayer, punyam

There are several incidents in scriptures where God/nature helps immediately in case of any danger or panic situation if one prays for help.

I can provide three such examples from Mahabharata:

#1: Krishna helping Draupadi by providing a saree.

#2: Krishna helping Draupadi from Durvasa's anger.

#3: Nature helping Damayanthi from a person in the forest.

There are numerous such incidents in which God helps immediately. But in each case, I can notice that help is offered to the person only if there is a deposit of Punya/tapas, etc.,

Are there any instances in scriptures where God helps a person, who prayed God in a panic situation, with no deposit of Punya available?

Comment: They were helped because of there good karma. By good I mean very very good karma.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah true. If someone has no good karma and asking God to help in a dangerous situation, will she help? That is my question.

Comment: no according to me because people who have bad karma do not have any kind of devotion and love for God. And they are getting in the dangerous situation because of there bad karma.

Comment: I dont think punya matters, what would matter is calling him or remembering him . Let's see if someone comes with an answer.

Comment: And how should we define or know that they (the person being helped by the divinity) didn't have any *puñya* in their kitty?

Comment: @Proxy u can help by upvoting the question

Comment: God/nature helps everyone equal manner, there is no point to offer help only for few people. Mode help might be different, most of time we might not noticed it.

Comment: @DarkKnight thanks for reminding, I did it much earlier.

Answer (score 4):

In [Kurma Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=16), Lord Shiva states that he always grants protection to his devotees.

> Parama Shiva asserted:
>
> Naaham Tapobhirvividhairna Daanena na cheyjyayaa,
>
> Shakyo hi Purushair jaaturmutey Bhaktiamanuttamaam/
>
> I am always realisable by Bhakti or Pure Devotion and not necessarily
> by Tapasya, Daana or Charity and Yagnaas!.
>
> Na madbhaktaa vinashyanti madbhaktaa veeta kalmashaah,
>
> Aadaavetat pratigjaanam na mey bhaktah pranashyati/
>
> Patram Pushpam Phalam toyam madaaraadhana kaaranaat,
>
> Yo mey dadaati niyatah sa meyBhaktah Priyomatah/
>
> **My Bhaktaas would never be destroyed nor harmed but would be washed off their sins as I took a vow that my Bhaktas are protected**.
> Bhaktas are merely required to perform my Puja with utmost sincerity
> and offer leaves, flowers, fruits and even water as I would be
> pleased.

The bold portion implies that all persons will receive Lord Shiva's protection and assistance even if they are sinners provided the persons are devotees.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no point in taking refuge in God if God only helps a good person. Where would a bad person go? Of course the bad person must sincerely try to be good.

> Nanda: "But how can we obtain God's grace? Has He really the power to
> bestow grace?"
>
> Sri Ramakrishna (smiling): "I see. You think as the intellectuals do;
> one reaps the results of one's actions. Give up these ideas. **The
> effect of Karma wears away if one takes refuge in God.** I prayed to the
> Divine Mother with flowers in my hand: 'Here, Mother, take Thy sin;
> here take Thy virtue. I don't want either of these; give me only real
> bhakti. Here, Mother, take Thy good; here take Thy bad. I don't want
> any of Thy good or bad; give me only real bhakti. Here, Mother, take
> Thy dharma; here, take Thy adharma. I don't want any of Thy dharma and
> adharma; give me only real bhakti. Here, Mother, take Thy knowledge;
> here take Thy ignorance. I don't want any of Thy knowledge or
> ignorance; give me only real bhakti. Here, Mother, take Thy purity;
> here take Thy impurity. Give me only real bhakti [devotion].'"

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 43, Visit to Nanda Bose's House**

An example would be the transformation of a dacoit Ratnakar to Valmiki with the help of Narada.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can be looked upon while discussing this topic:

1. What is a Punya Deposit?

> A Punya Deposit can be called as collections of remaining of all the good deeds which we have performed and all the bad deeds which are done by us. Based on scriptures, the karma transfers to the next birth of any "Atma". So if one has committed a crime in a previous life and has not got his punishment, then he/she might face that in the present life.

2. Is there any chance to distrust God?

> As you have written, "Does God help..?". God always helps us in one form or the other. IF somebody is helping you out with any small thing or from any big problem, do you think it is automatic and there is no involvement of God in it?
> The thing is, God always helps their children either he/she is a sinner or a good person. It depends on what deed is being committed. Is it for the good or for the bad?

The examples are very good examples. Now think about the Asuras. Kansa, hiranyakashyap, Ravana, and all those demons. They all did the most demonic things in their life. But God has helped them as well. Don't think that they were killed by God? They got "Moksha" in that manner.

I hope this will help and please suggest if anyone finds any related example/fact.